# Using api calls in promise function

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, axios

I'm not fully understanding how promises work. I made a function that executes an api call that uses a promise.

```
function getSomeData(email, password) {
    axios.post('SomeURL/login', {
    email: email,
    password: password
  })
}
```

Whenever this function fires i can get the data that i want. But whenever an error occurs the error will show up within the `.then()` call rather then the `.catch()`

```
getSomeData().then(data => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

How can i make sure that, when i call `.catch()` it will show my error there instead of in the `.then()`

Comment: Where does an error show up?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the promise like this:

```
function getSomeData(email, password) {
    return axios.post('SomeURL/login', {
        email: email,
        password: password
    })
}
```

Then it should be working (if the `axios.post` call returns promise).

Comment: This is what is returned with then even though i inserted a wrong email adress `{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}` (i get it back from .then())

Comment: Well that sounds like an error in the API processing your request.

Comment: I'm really certain the api works. Within the data: {} it will return an error array with details about what went wrong :(

Comment: Well it might return error data correctly, but from what you send here, it returns status code 200 OK, and that is the reason why its not falling to the `catch` handler.

Comment: Could it be that the .catch() on an axios function will only trigger if something is wrong with the api call rather then with the data that gets returned?

Comment: Well as I said, I believe the problem is in your API, that is not returning correct response status code in case of error. You should debug this first, ideally via some REST client, like Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if statement to handle business logic errors.  Then the catch error will handle server errors.

```
function getSomeData(email, password) {

  return axios.post('SomeURL/login', {
    email: email,
    password: password
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (response.statusText === 'OK') {
      // LOGIN SUCCESS
      // Do something with the login result
    } else {
      // LOGIN FAILURE, but not server failure
      // Redirect to login page, and give a message
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  // API is down
  })
}
```